# url validation RegExp recognize email address as url

Tags: javascript, regex, url-validation

I have to recognize url in some text.
I use the following code (`this.value` is the text):

```
if (new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(this.value)) {
    alert("url inside");
}
```

The problem that is recognize also email address as url.
How can I prevent it?

Comment: That regex will only match some URIs (eg. local/experimental protocols should start "x-"). If you don't want to match all protocols it would help to know which ones you do want to match?

Comment: @Richard- I want a match for all protocols

Comment: `mailto:` is then a valid match... or perhaps you shouldn't make the protocol optional?

Comment: @Richard- the protocol should matches only to url, not to email address

Comment: "I want a match for all protocols" "not to email address" --- so make decision, all or not? All means literally **all**.

Comment: Please include in the question a series of things you want to match and a series of things you do not want to match: covering your full requirement because I'm getting less confident I know what you mean. "Email address" for example is ambiguous here given your regex makes the protocol optional.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/` is the same as `/\w/i`.

The original RegExp matches the "domain.org" substring in a text like "text name@domain.org text mailto:name@domain-2.org text". To fix this add `(?:^|[^@\.\w-])` at the beginning of the RegExp - a substring should be at the beginning of a line or should not begin with characters '@', '.', '-', '\w'.

To exclude "mailto:user@..." substrings the expression `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?` should be modified. Because Javascript RegExp has no look-behind expressions the only way to exclude "mailto" is to use the look-ahead expression `\w(?!ailto:)\w+:`, but all substrings like "[a-zA-Z0-9_]ailto:...@..." will be excluded also.

To exclude from matches the substring "user.name" from a text like "text user.name@domain.org text" add the expression `(?=$|[^@\.\w-])` at the ending of the RegExp - match a substring only if the end of line follows the substring or the following characters '@', '.', '-', '\w' don't follow the substring.

```js
var re = /(?:^|[^@\.\w-])([a-z0-9]+:\/\/)?(\w(?!ailto:)\w+:\w+@)?([\w.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(\/.*)?(?=$|[^@\.\w-])/im;

//if (re.test(this.value)) {
//    alert("url inside");
//}

var s1 = "text name@domain.org name.lastname@domain-2.org text mailto:user.name@domain-3.org text";
if (re.test(s1)) {
    alert("Failed: text without URL");
}

var s2 = "text http://domain.org/ text";
if (!re.test(s2)) {
    alert("Failed: text with URL");
}

alert("OK");
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.